# Using modulus operator in IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement, modulus

I am trying to use a modulus in my if statement, however I cannot get it working or find an example of this anywhere and it is not the same as in other languages I have done. So far ive tried

```
if ($counter % "10" = 2)
  {
    echo ($counter);
  echo "Have a good morning!";
  }
```

and

```
if ($counter % 10 = 2)
  {
    echo ($counter);
  echo "Have a good morning!";
  }
```

and

```
if (($counter % "10") = 2)
  {
    echo ($counter);
  echo "Have a good morning!";
  }
```

Yet still nothing is working, I am getting the error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in H:\STUDENT\S0190204\GGJ\index.php on line 50
```

Although that is probably because the syntax is incorrect, if anyone could shed some light on this or point me in the direction of a site that shows a modulus used in an if statement in php Id appreciate it.
Thank you

Comment: `=` assignment; `==` comparison

Comment: Yo u should use == for checks. = is for assignment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an error in your `if` statements.

```
if ($counter % 10 = 2)
```

should be

```
if ($counter % 10 == 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following statement. Your statement is wrong written

```
if ($counter % 10 == 2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes above is right use compare operator(==) not assignment(=) 
and also take care of operator precedence by using ()
try this
if (($counter % 10) == 2)

Comment: Operator Precedence is only needed in this case if you assign like `($result = ($counter % 10))` . Otherwise it's pretty redundant and doesn't help clarity in this case at all.

Comment: Yes i agree with you but i think, it is good practice to take care of precedence always :)